# Reduce duplication when overloading functions in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have a function that takes an array and converts it to an object of some sort. The input array can be `undefined`, in which case the function returns `undefined`:

```
function toNdArray(arr: number[] | undefined): ndarray | undefined {
  return arr && ndarray(arr);
}
```

If I call this function with a variable of type `number[] | undefined`, the result has type `ndarray | undefined` as expected:

```
(arr: number[] | undefined) => {
    const result = toNdArray(arr);
    // => actual = wanted = `ndarray | undefined`
}
```

However, if I call the function with an array that I known for sure is defined, **I'd like the result to have type `ndarray`**, not `ndarray | undefined`, so I can use it right away without having to cast it (e.g. `as ndarray`) or use a type guard (e.g. `isDefined()`):

```
const result = toNdArray([0, 1, 2]);
// => actual = `ndarray | undefined`
// => wanted: `ndarray`
```

One solution is to use [function overloading](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads):

```
function toNdArray(arr:number[]): ndarray;
function toNdArray(arr:number[] | undefined): ndarray | undefined;
function toNdArray(arr: number[] | undefined): ndarray | undefined {
  return arr && ndarray(arr);
}
```

This works great but it's very verbose. What I find annoying is to have to duplicate the full signature of `toNdArray` (i.e. the second overload). If I don't and specify only the first overload, the first use case above no longer works because TS doesn't include the implementation of `toNdArray` in the overload list (as explained in the TS docs):

```
function toNdArray(arr:number[]): ndarray;
function toNdArray(arr: number[] | undefined): ndarray | undefined {
  return arr && ndarray(arr);
}

(arr: number[] | undefined) => {
    const result = toNdArray(arr); // TS error
}
```

The duplication isn't too bad in the example above, but in a real-world example, in a project where Prettier splits long function signatures over multiple lines, it can really bloat the code. I've put the code above [in a TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAdgJgQwE5ISKBeKBvAvgbgCgAzAVxgGNgBLAexlkRTQAoB9ALllIFsAjCEgDaAXQCUXeMlTpsUJBGCkkDPFFyES5KnQbBaAOTgBBZiBbSOMXgOHjJTGUQD0zqGUo16UfUdMyLFCsbQVEoAB8ocjgIYmoYCDgJRmk0CKj4WPjEog8db18TM0CkSRC7dOishKSHVPRIqrianEIodvlFZQZpKAAyPpTi6TEiDUISsv5QkUrM5sSxTAA+Vo6oCnoAZ2BOrdIAG12sQv9WEbHNTZgdvcPjn0MigKEABgAaKABGT4AmcSIQA) in case you'd like to play with it.

So my questions are the following:

- Is there a way to reduce duplication in such a simple overloading scenario?
- Is there an alternative to function overloading that can achieve the same result with less bloat? Perhaps a conditional return type? My attempts have been unsuccessful so far, but perhaps I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: "*What I find annoying is to have to duplicate the full signature of toNdArray (i.e. the second overload)*" but your **second overload** should be  `function toNdArray(arr: undefined): undefined;` - it's not a duplicate. Your *actual* method signature should be merging all above and than one will be using unions for input/output `number[] | undefined`. Although you could also just declare them `any` - the real function signature still accepts the ones above. You lose some type safety there, though but it might not be an issue.

Comment: following what @VLAZ has mentioned, look at it like this: each overload signature is actually just "if these parameters, then this result" while the signature on the implementation is just for your own type safety within the context of that function.

Comment: I can understand the bloat problem, but that's a common question in structuring TS code - "how precise do I want this to be" in relation "how much code do I want to write for this". In examples with `null` and `undefined`, you can maybe leave the union type and use the "new" [optional changing and nullish operators](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html) on the result to skip the type guard. In other, more complex examples, you'd either have to write complex infer result type wrappers for each use case or accept the overload bloat.

Comment: Using `function toNdArray(arr: undefined): undefined` does not work, as [this playground shows](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAdgJgQwE5ISKBeKBvAvgbgCgAzAVxgGNgBLAexlkRTQAoB9ALllIFsAjCEgDaAXQCUXeMlTpsUJBGCkkDPFFyES5KnQbBaAOTgBBZiBbTJvAcPGSmMomUo16UfUdMyLKLuTgQxNQwEHASUP6BwaFO2q56hiZmPkhW-IKiUAA+EfBRIWH20mjZuQFBBTiEUDXyisoM0lAAZM2MxebSYkQahClpNpk5kRWhYpgAfFW1UBT0AM7AdfOkADZLWB5J3l09mnMwi8trG+6JXqxCAAwANFAAjHcATOJEQA). If it did, it would indeed be a bit more concise :'(

Comment: @5ar, what do you mean by "infer result type wrappers"?

Comment: @Axel It works (sort of), but the problem is you're not passing `number[]` or `undefined`, but their union `number[] | undefined` which is a different type and can't be cast to just one of those. If the `arr` argument was precisely  `number[]` or precisely `undefined` it would infer the result correctly, but since you don't know what `arr` is before runtime (according to that call), neither can TS.

Comment: Oh yeah, I get that, that's why I wrapped my first example in an anonymous function to show that I'm working with a variable of type `number[] | undefined` that cannot be inferred further.

Comment: @Axel You could write something like `type MyFunctionXResult<TArg> = TArg extends something ? ResultA : ResultB` for `function myFunctionX<TArg>(arg: TArg): MyFunctionXResult<TArg>` but this can get really fiddly and complex to get right in a lot of scenarios

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225158/discussion-between-axel-and-5ar).

Comment: @Axel `function toNdArray(arr: undefined): undefined` doesn't work *with unions*. My understanding is that you want to say that if an array is passed in, you get `ndarray` out, if you pass `undefined`, you get `undefined`. This doesn't allow a mixed input. If you *want* mixed input, then you also need another overload. There is no shorter alternative here - that's how overloads work. And overloads are the *correct* way of implementing this behaviour. You can get shorter things but they would lack clarity and/or correctness.

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot! If someone comes up with an alternative to the overloads that solves the same problem (`number[] | undefined => ndarray | undefined` + `number[] => ndarray`), I'd still be very curious to see what it looks like -- even if it takes more code. It might help me solve more complex scenarios. As mentioned, I tried with conditional return types, but I didn't get far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding a [working solution](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAdgJgQwE5ISKBeKBvAvgbgCgAzAVxgGNgBLAexlkRTQAoB9ALllIFsAjCEgDaAXQCUXeMlTpsUJBGCkkDPFFyES5KnQbBaAOTgBBZiAA8AFSgQAHsAjwAzt36DRUAD5RycCMWoYCDgAPhZpLksJKGs7B2dXAWERKAB+Rmk0KC5ff0DgojJKGnoofSNTGXCUSV4kj29cgKC4aKkzLx94PJacQigB+UVlBmkoADJxjLNqpDEiDUJZ2rdkzqb81swQvsGoCnonYCGnUgAbY6xykxnpecJFg5gjk-PLssMbqqEABgAaKAARgBACZxEQgA) with a single override and a conditional return type:

```
function toNdArray<T extends number[] | undefined>(arr: T): T extends number[] ? ndarray : undefined;

function toNdArray(arr: number[] | undefined): ndarray | undefined {
    return arr && ndarray(arr);
}
```

In my initial attempts, I had tried to put the conditional return type directly on the implementation signature instead of adding an override.